# Parent property of derived TreeNode class

Tags: c#

I'm using a class derived from TreeNode so I can add custom properties to each node

```
public class CustomNode : TreeNode
{
    public int preloadIndex;
    public string uniqueID = "0";
    public int layer;
    public string internalName;
    public bool lsActive;
}
```

At some point my code is collecting a bunch of nodes into a List, and I need to get custom properties from the parents of each of those nodes.

```
List<CustomNode> NodeList = new List<CustomNode>;
//some nodes are collected into the list

foreach (var aNode in NodeList)
{
    CustomNode parentNode = (CustomNode)aNode.Parent;
    int parentIndex = parentNode.preloadIndex;
    string parentID = parentNode.uniqueID;
}
```

The problem is aNode.Parent returns a TreeNode instead of my custom class, and casting it like I've tried above doesn't work.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in myProject.exe
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode' to type 'myProject.CustomNode'.

Casting `aNode.parent as CustomNode` doesn't work eiher, it returns `null`.
`TreeNodeCollection.Find` also returns a `TreeNode`.

Is there any way to get a parent node, preferably without looping through the entire `TreeView`?

Comment: How did you declare the Parent property ?  I guess it is in the TreeNode class - but what's its type ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but have you tried "aNode.Parent as CustomNode"?

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN I haven't declared it, it's inherited from the base TreeNode class. This looks like the cause of my problem now that you mentioned it. Is there any way I could define the Parent property as a CustomNode and at the same time keep it's functionality?

Comment: @Rariolu Thanks but I already tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is the concept of inheritance. Basically put, you can't make an object become something it has never been. Just because `CustomNode` derives from `TreeNode` doesn't mean any `TreeNode` is a `CustomNode`.

Really the solution lies in code you haven't shown us, namely the creation of your `TreeView`. It is here that you need to create an instance of your `CustomNode` and add it to your `TreeView`. Your `CustomNode` could override or 'shadow' event and properties according to your needs.

In your case, another solution might be found in your `NodeList` object. If, **and only if**, every `CustomNode` you need is in that list, including all parents and children, then you could simply change the `List` to a `Dictionary` with the key being the `CustomNode.Name` property. So your code would become:

```
        var nodeList = new Dictionary<string, CustomNode>();
        //some nodes are collected into the list, like this:
        var cn = new CustomNode();
        nodeList.Add(cn.Name, cn);

        foreach (var aNode in nodeList.Values)
        {
            var parentNode = nodeList[aNode.Parent.Name];
            int parentIndex = parentNode.preloadIndex;
            string parentID = parentNode.uniqueID;
        }
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I was under the impression that my `TreeView.Nodes` contains only `CustomNode` objects, but it turns out a few were `TreeNode`, and those were causing the problem. Thank you for pointing it out. Your `Dictionary` solution is also interesting, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: No, the `Dictionary` solution is a weak workaround. If you can sort out your `TreeView` issue then that's definitely the way to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Write an override of the Parent method in your CustomNode.
(Untested code)

```
public class CustomNode : TreeNode
{
    public int preloadIndex;
    public string uniqueID = "0";
    public int layer;
    public string internalName;
    public bool lsActive;

    public new CustomNode Parent()
    {
        return (CustomNode)base.Parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code returns the same error when it tries to cast `(CustomNode)base.Parent`

Comment: Actually your code should be correct. As pointed out by @Ambie, the cause lied somewhere else in my code. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Radu, Change your code into :

```
CustomNode parentNode = aNode.Parent as CustomNode;
if ( parentNode != null ){
    int parentIndex = parentNode.preloadIndex;
    string parentID = parentNode.uniqueID;
}
```

The as operator returns null if it's not a CustomNode

Regards